# XDocument, XElement : Sequence contains no matching element

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

Searching element of xml file using C# but getting following

**Error:** Sequence contains no matching element

```
    XNamespace siteNM = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0";
            XDocument sitemap = new XDocument
                (new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null), 
                     new XElement(siteNM + "siteMap", 
                          new XElement(siteNM + "siteMapNode", new XAttribute("title", "Home"), new XAttribute("url", "home.aspx"), new XAttribute("description", "Home"))
                                 ));
    XElement x = sitemap.Root;
```

I have tried following **two methods** for searching element but both give me **same error**.

**1st way:**

```
XElement child = x.Descendants("siteMapNode").Where(el => el.Attribute("title") != null && el.Attribute("title").Value == "Home").First();
```

**2nd Way:**

```
XElement child1 = x.Descendants("siteMapNode").First(el => (string)el.Attribute("title") == "Home");
```

please help me.
Thank you so much..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

missing namespace

```
XElement child = x.Descendants(siteNM + "siteMapNode")
                .First(el => el.Attribute("title") != null && el.Attribute("title").Value == "Home");
```

Comment: Thank you so much ......you are completely right...it helps me a lot...thank you so much once again...

Answer (score 2):

You probably should add namespece in search query as well:

```
XElement child = x.Descendants(siteNM + "siteMapNode").Where(el => el.Attribute("title") != null && el.Attribute("title").Value == "Home").First();
```